# How to delete multiple certs from keystore

Tags: keytool

I have one keystore which has around 30 certificates i want to delete most of them.

How can i do it rather than doing `keytool -delete -alias <AliasName> -keystore keystore.jks`

Comment: You can only do it one by one using `keytool`.